# how to save ArrayLists Position at orientation change

Tags: java, android

I'm currently facing a bug in restoring the Position of an ArrayList after orientation cchange to enhance the user experience. I try to store the ArrayList and already made movieData Parcelable. When using a debugger after orientation change savedInstance obviously is not null and contained an int value and presumably the parcelable Array List and I don't really know why this code doesn't work yet.

Fragment Class:

```
public class MovieGridFragment extends Fragment {

    public clickInterfaceHelper clickListener;
    private GridView movieGridView;
    private int index;
    public List<movieData> movieDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<movieData> restoreList;

    public MovieGridFragment() {} //empty constructor

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    public void setClickListener(clickInterfaceHelper listener) {
        this.clickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null)
            index = savedInstanceState.getInt("INDEX");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        if(movieDataList.isEmpty() && networkChecker.isNetworkAvailableChecker(getContext())) {
            movieDataList = new ArrayList<movieData>();
        }

        if(!movieDataList.isEmpty() && !networkChecker.isNetworkAvailableChecker(getContext())) {
            movieDataList = new ArrayList<movieData>();
        }



        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_display_fragment, container, false);

        movieGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gv_movie_display);

        if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("OLDMOVIEDATA")) {
            //index = savedInstanceState.getInt("INDEX");
            //movieDataList.addAll(Arrays.asList((movieData[]) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("OLDMOVIEDATA")));
            restoreList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("OLDMOVIEDATA");
            movieAdapter adapter = new movieAdapter(getActivity(),restoreList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //movieGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            movieGridView.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
        }
        else {
            movieAdapter adapter = new movieAdapter(getActivity(), movieDataList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            movieGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        movieGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(clickListener != null)
                        clickListener.clickOnItem(position);

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //outState.putSerializable("OLDMOVIEDATA",movieData.movieDataArray);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("OLDMOVIEDATA",restoreList);
        outState.putInt("INDEX",movieGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


}
```

Adapter:

```
public class movieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<movieData> {

    public movieAdapter(Context context, List<movieData> movieObject) {
        super(context, 0, movieObject);
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View convertingView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        movieData movieDatas = getItem(pos);
        String url="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185"+movieDatas.getMovieImagePath();

        if(convertingView == null)
            convertingView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_display,viewGroup,false);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertingView.findViewById(R.id.iv_movie_image);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url.trim()).into(imageView);
        return convertingView;
    }
}
```

and the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements clickInterfaceHelper {

    public static String sorterString = null;
    public static String urlBase = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
    public static String urlFinal = null;

    RequestQueue requestQueue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            MovieGridFragment fragment = new MovieGridFragment();
                    fragment.setClickListener(this);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.activity_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            movieData.movieDataPosition = 0;
        }
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            sorterString = savedInstanceState.getString("SORTER");
        }

        if(sorterString==null)
            sorterString="popular?";
        if(sorterString!="favorite" && sorterString!=null) {
            if(networkChecker.isNetworkAvailableChecker(this)) {
                movieRequest();
            }
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu_act, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.m_popularity_action) {
            if(sorterString != "popular?") {
                sorterString = "popular?";
                if(networkChecker.isNetworkAvailableChecker(this))
                movieRequest();
            }
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.m_action_voter) {
            if(sorterString != "top_rated?") {
                sorterString = "top_rated?";
                if(networkChecker.isNetworkAvailableChecker(this))
                movieRequest();
            }
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.m_favorite_btn) {
            if(sorterString != "favorite") {
                SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new movieDataDbHelper(this);
                SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor= database.query(movieDataContract.contractEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[] {
                                movieDataContract.contractEntry.ID,
                                movieDataContract.contractEntry.IMG_PATH},null,null,null,null,null);
                if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "there are no favorite movies yet!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    sorterString = "favorite";
                    showFavoriteFragment();
                }
                database.close();
                helper.close();
                cursor.close();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void showFavoriteFragment() {
        favoriteMoviesDetailsFragment fragment = new favoriteMoviesDetailsFragment();
        try {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_container,fragment).commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        outState.putString("SORTER", sorterString);
        outState.putInt("POSITION",movieData.movieDataPosition);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    }

    public void movieRequest() {
        final MovieGridFragment gridFragment = new MovieGridFragment();
        gridFragment.setClickListener(this);
            urlFinal = urlBase + sorterString + movieData.apiKey;
            urlFinal.trim();
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlFinal, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("results");
                        movieData.movieDataArray = new movieData[array.length()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            movieData movie = new movieData();
                            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            movie.setMovieId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                            movie.setMovieImagePath(jsonObject.getString("poster_path"));
                            movie.setMovieTitle(jsonObject.getString("original_title"));
                            movie.setMoviePlot(jsonObject.getString("overview"));
                            movie.setMovieVoting(jsonObject.getString("vote_average"));
                            movie.setMovieReleaseDate(jsonObject.getString("release_date"));
                            movieData.movieDataArray[i] = movie;
                        }


                        gridFragment.movieDataList = Arrays.asList(movieData.movieDataArray);
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.activity_container, gridFragment);
                        try {
                            transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("volley", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            }
            );
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public void clickOnItem(int id) {
        movieData.movieDataPosition = id;
        if(movieData.movieDataArray == null) {
            movieRequest();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, detailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("FRAGMENT","MOVIE");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void favoriteMovieItem(int movieId) {
        movieData.dbPosition = movieId;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,detailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("FRAGMENT","favorite");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already use the

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //outState.putSerializable("OLDMOVIEDATA",movieData.movieDataArray);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("OLDMOVIEDATA",restoreList);
    outState.putInt("INDEX",movieGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Just use it to store the position you need to save. Get the position back using the bundle given in the "onCreateView".

If it does not work, put "setRetainInstance(true)" in the "onCreate" function of your fragment. It will prevent your fragment being destroyed then recreated from nothing during orientation change.
However, I read somewhere that's not the correct way to do so with fragment having UI elements (but i never found anything wrong doing this).

If you want an alternative way not using "setRetainInstance", store (and restore) the position on the activity

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)"
```

function. To do so, create a function "getPosition()" in your fragment, call it in the activity saveInstanceState, and create a function "refresh(int position)" in your fragment (and call it on the restored position value) once the fragment is loaded/recreated in the activity.

Comment: so i just added setRetainInstance to true in the onCreate which doesnt change anything. I'm getting the index from the savedInstanceBundle in onCreateView and use smoothScrollTo(index) which apparently doesn't work. Which part am i getting wrong?

Comment: wow i'm also restoring the restoreList in onSaveInstance which gets assigned to a value only if savedInstance != null

Comment: First of all : when restoring, did you get the correct index value, or is that a problem to set the view on the correct position ?
Another possible problem : you may used an index already in use for android. Rename your variable key in the bundle to something like "packagename.ActivityClass.VariableName" to be sure not to interfere with some android saved data. "INDEX" is not long and custom enought to be sure.

Comment: when using a debugger after orientation change index had a fitting value, so the problem must be restoring the view.

Comment: then, i'm sorry, i'm not bad at programing algorithms and shit, but i'm having hard times to do things in the UI (not only in android)... As you get the correct index value now, there may be a problem with restoring the view as you stated, but i can't help you on that. Try searching on how to set the index correctly.